# Can't start MySQL: "Could not find domain for" running mysql on macos (Laravel Valet)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, homebrew, laravel-valet

I'm trying to get a local mysql up and running on my macos machine. I am following theese instructions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet#installation

- I am installing through Homebrew.
- I have tried reinstalling mysql
- I have two users: an administrator to install things, and a normal user account for my developing and normal activities. Perhaps this is what's causing the issues

### What I expect:

MySQL to run every time I boot up my macbook as it used to do (no matter what user account I am logged into, preferably).

### Error:

When I try to connect through Sequel Pro or running `mysql -u root` directly, I get error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

### What I have tried

- `sudo brew services restart mysql@5.7`. Running with success but mysql still doesn't work.
- `[admin:~]$ brew services start mysql@5.7` error `Could not find domain for Error: Failure while executing; /bin/launchctl enable gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7 exited with 112.`
- Followed instructions of: [MacOSX: autostart mysql on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014500)
- Tried starting manually from my normal user account: `[myuser:~]$ mysql.server start` error: `Starting MySQL ./usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.24/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/mymacname.local.err: Permission denied`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacOSX: autostart mysql on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014500/macosx-autostart-mysql-on-boot)

Answer (score 3):

So I finally found the solution, turned out it was quite simple. I tried reinstalling several times, etc, but in the end what worked was to fix the permissions brew didn't manage to, after a installing via brew.

Running

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

Then restarting the mysql server:

```
sudo brew services restart mysql@5.7
```

Solved the issue

Comment: Absolutely outrageous - this solved the problem for me as well. I don't understand why there were no error messages (that I could find, at least) that pointed to this solution, but simply chowning `/usr/local/var/mysql` (and its contents) allowed mysql to run at boot. Thank you for posting this!

Comment: this is hilarious. this solved my problem after hours and hours of trying